# Why currentTarget value is null

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I am learing `event.target` and `event.currentTarget`. I think i am clear with the difference between the two. But stuck in a situation where `event.currentTarget` value turns out to be null.

Following are the HTML and JS code snippets:

HTML code

```
<form id="form">
   This is a form
</form>
```

JavaScript Code

```
 form.addEventListener('click', func);

 function func(event) {
    console.log(event.target.tagName);  //line1
    console.log(event.currentTarget.tagName); //line2

    setTimeout(()=> {
       console.log(event.target.tagName);  //line3
       console.log(event.currentTarget.tagName); //line4
    }, 0)  ;
 }
```

My doubt is that in line1 and line3 I got the value of `event.target` the same. But there is a difference in the value of `event.currentTarget` in line2 and line4.

The output in line3 is 'form', but in line4 it is:

> *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of null*.

That means **`currentTarget` is null in line4**.

**Can you explain why value of `currentTarget` is `null` in line4 ?**

Answer (score 44, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget. Note the line

> **Note:** The value of `event.currentTarget` is only available while the event is being handled. If you `console.log()` the event object, storing it in a variable, and then look for the `currentTarget` key in the console, its value will be null`.

Answer (score 4):

currentTarget has some special behavior read the documantaion from [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) or for more details please check this   [why-is-event-currenttarget-null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53811586/why-is-event-currenttarget-null-and-e-target-always-the-same)