# In React, why does my website crash when I type too fast in the TextField?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

In my app, when I type too fast into the TextField, my website crashes and I see a blank white screen.

Here is the code.

TextField Code:

```
<TextField
            label="Item name"
            variant="filled"
            required
            color="primary"
            onChange={handleItemNameChange}
            id={`${id}`}
            defaultValue={items[id][0]}
/>
```

handleItemNameChange:

```
const handleItemNameChange = (event) => {
    let index = event.currentTarget.id;
    setItems((items) => {
        const tempItems = \[...items\];
       tempItems\[index\]\[0\] = event.currentTarget.value;
       return tempItems;
});
};
```

The console error I get is as follows when I type too fast:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')

This error comes from the line:
tempItems[index][0] = event.currentTarget.value;

This issue only comes up when I type quite fast into the TextField.

Would greatly appreciate any help in solving this issue!

This issue does not come when I type slowly into the TextField and only occurs when I type a little fast into it. I feel it has something to do with the setItems hook as the Items array gets updated quite often?

Comment: use ? like `event.currentTarget?.value`

Comment: Hi, please check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/66086044/14953535. I hope it will be useful for you

Answer (score 1):

The function passed to `setItem` is not executed immediately, and by the time it is, it might be that the browser reused the event object for something else. You should store `event.currentTarget.value` in a variable outside of that function, just like you do with `index`.

Answer (score -2):

"value is undefined", I don't see a value attribute anywhere.